# How to convert hexadecimal to Int24 in python?

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I am actually not sure if I am asking the correct question. But here is the picture I have question about
[image]

so I am trying to parse a binary file, I want to grab information at column 00, 04, 08, 0C and retrieve their information (int24)

What I do first is get the hexa on the column, then convert it to the text as shown the code below

```
output = []
f = open(binary, 'rb')
    bytes = 0
    fileContents = f.read()
    idx = 0
    for b in fileContents:
        bytes = bytes+1
        hexa = '{0:0{1}x}'.format(b, 2)
        text = str(int(hexa, 24))
        if idx % 4 == 0:
           output.append(text)
        idx +=1
```

However, the text O got is int8 instead of Int24, for example at "2C", I want it show 300, but all the convertion I tried whether it is int 16, 24, 43 is converting it to 44 (int8), What do I do to convert it to Int24 or 32 or so on?

Thanks

Comment: Make a [mcve].  Your single line doesn't define how `b` was created.  Knowing some detail about the binary format would be helpful as well.

Comment: Suggested research: `struct.unpack` and `int.from_bytes`.

Comment: I can add more code for how I am parsing the binary file

Comment: You don't have hexadecimal.  You have binary.  If you want three bytes at a time, then just read three bytes at a time.  `f.read(3)`.

Comment: sorry I am still not understanding, I refactor the quesiton a little bit, can you help, I think it's my misudnerstanding at how binary works but I am confused and don't know where to go

Comment: Int24 is an odd size. I think you want int32 (4 bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Various ways to read the file displayed.  I assume you really want 4-byte integers as 3-byte (int24) is on odd size and the file appears to be 4-byte integers.

```py
import struct
import array

# Generate file shown.
# L means 4-byte unsigned integer, Q means 8-byte unsigned integer.
data = struct.pack('<80L6Q', *([0x48]*80 + [0, 0x3c, 0x78, 0xb4, 0xf0, 0x12c]))
with open('data.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)

# read 4 bytes at a time and convert to little-endian 32-bit integer.
with open('data.bin', 'rb') as f:
    while data := f.read(4):
        print(int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='little'), end=' ')
    print()

# read the whole file as a 32-bit integer array.
with open('data.bin', 'rb') as f:
    data = array.array('L', f.read())  # L means 4-byte unsigned integer
    print(data)

# read the whole file and unpack it as 80 4-byte integers and 6 8-byte integers
# as that appears to be the structure of the data.
with open('data.bin', 'rb') as f:
    data = struct.unpack('<80L6Q', f.read())
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 72 0 0 60 0 120 0 180 0 240 0 300 0 
array('L', [72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 0, 0, 60, 0, 120, 0, 180, 0, 240, 0, 300, 0])
(72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300)
```

References:

- [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module
- [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes)
- [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module